# Issues using expo-sqlite in react native app to display records from a table

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, expo-sqlite

I'm doing a react native app to manage notes and tasks.

I have two tables for each one. The problem is:
I can save and display the notes without any problem. I try to do the same with the tasks. The task are created, displayed on the component, but when I reload or cloese the app, the task is gone.

The components are pretty the same. with some additions for the tasks.

These are my components:

-To create a task:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { useDataContext } from '../dataProviders/DataProvider';
import { db } from '../database/database';

export default function CreateTasks() {
    const { handleAddTask } = useDataContext();

    const [taskTitle, setTaskTitle] = useState('');
    const [taskDate, setTaskDate] = useState('');
    const [taskTime, setTaskTime] = useState('');
    const [taskDescription, setTaskDescription] = useState('');

    const addTask = () => {
        const newValue = {
            taskTitle: taskTitle,
            date: taskDate,
            time: taskTime,
            taskDescription: taskDescription,
        };
        setTaskTitle(newValue.taskTitle);
        setTaskDate(newValue.date);
        setTaskTime(newValue.time);
        setTaskDescription(newValue.taskDescription);
        db.transaction(
            (tx) => {
                tx.executeSql(
                    'insert into tasks ( title, date, time, description) values(?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    [newValue.taskTitle, newValue.date, newValue.time, newValue.taskDescription]
                );
            },
        );
        handleAddTask(newValue);
        setTaskTitle(''); // Clear the input fields
        setTaskDate('');
        setTaskTime('');
        setTaskDescription('');
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <ScrollView style={styles.inputArea}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputTitle}
                    value={taskTitle}
                    onChangeText={taskTitle => setTaskTitle(taskTitle)}
                    placeholder='Task'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputDate}
                    value={taskDate}
                    onChangeText={date => setTaskDate(date)}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    placeholder='xx/xx/xxxx'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputTime}
                    value={taskTime}
                    onChangeText={time => setTaskTime(time)}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    placeholder='00:00'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={taskDescription}
                    onChangeText={taskDescription => setTaskDescription(taskDescription)}
                    multiline={true}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    placeholder='Description...'
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Pressable onPress={() => addTask()}>
                    <Icon
                        name={"bookmark"}
                        //color="#87CEFA"
                        size={40}
                    />
                </Pressable>
            </View> 
        </View>  
    )
}
```

-To display the tasks:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable, Alert } from 'react-native';
import TaskContainer from './TaskContainer';
import EditTasks from './EditTasks';
import { useDataContext } from '../dataProviders/DataProvider';
import { getTasks, insertIntoDeletedTasks, removeTask } from '../database/database';
import { Provider } from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

export default function Tasks() {
  const { taskItems, setTaskItems } = useDataContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedTasks = await getTasks();
        setTaskItems(fetchedTasks);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching notes:', error);
        Alert.alert('Error fetching tasks. Please try again.');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    
  const regex = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i');
  const filteredData = taskItems.filter(item =>
      regex.test(item.taskTitle)
  );

  const moveTaskToDeletedTasks = async (taskData) => {
    try {
      insertIntoDeletedTasks(taskData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error moving note to deletedNotes:', error);
      throw new Error('Error moving note to deletedNotes.');
    }
  };

  const deleteTask = (index) => {
    // Show a confirmation dialog
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete Task',
      'Are you sure you want to delete this task?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          style: 'destructive',
          onPress: () => {
            // If the user confirms, delete the task
            let deletedTask = taskItems[index];
            // Move the note to deletedNotes table
            moveTaskToDeletedTasks(deletedTask);

            // Remove the note from noteItems
            let itemsCopyTask = [...taskItems];
            itemsCopyTask.splice(index, 1);
            setTaskItems(itemsCopyTask);

            // Perform the actual deletion of the note from the Notes table
            removeTask(deletedTask);
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider>
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.searchBox}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChangeText={(text) => setSearchQuery(text)}
            value={searchQuery}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <Icon
            name="search-outline"
            size={40}
          />
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {filteredData.map((item, index) => (
              item && item.taskTitle ? ( // Check if 'item' exists and has a 'title' property
                <Pressable
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() => deleteTask(index)}
                >
                  <TaskContainer
                    taskTitle={item.taskTitle}
                    date={item.date}
                    time={item.time}
                    taskDescription={item.taskDescription}
                    index={index}
                    task={item}
                  />
                </Pressable>
              ) : null
            ))}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <EditTasks />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

-The task container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { useDataContext } from '../dataProviders/DataProvider';


export default function TaskContainer(props) {

    const { showDialogTask } = useDataContext();
    const { task } = props;

    return (
        <View styles={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.TaskContainer}>
                <View style={styles.box1}>
                    <View style={styles.box11}>
                        <Text style={styles.titleItem}>Task</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text} ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>{task.taskTitle}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.box2}>
                    <View style={styles.box22}>
                        <Text style={styles.titleItem}>Date</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{task.date}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.box22}>
                        <Text style={styles.titleItem}>Time</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{task.time}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.box3}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.text} ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>{task.taskDescription}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.box4}>
                    <Pressable onPress={() => showDialogTask(task)}>
                        <Icon
                            name="create-outline"
                            size={40}
                        />
                    </Pressable>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Tried to debug with chatgpt. Nothing worked.

Thanks for any help or feedback!

Comment: Consider adding `console.log("num tasks:", taskItems?.length); console.log("num filtered:", filteredData?.length);` just before the `return()` in `Tasks` and see what it outputs when the data isn't displaying.

Comment: Your question details not complete, you saying not working, you haven't include any error message, just log what happen on insert part and the select query

Comment: @GregFenton I got the following log: 
LOG  num tasks: 18
LOG  num filtered: 18.
I have some console.logs when adding the tasks or notes. At least in these logs I get that it was added.
The issue must be on the Task component or on the TaskContainer, but I can't see a thing. :'(

Comment: Does it log the same count both when the UI renders the tasks and when it does not render the tasks?  Maybe put a `console.log("task item is:", item);` just before the `return` in TaskContainer and see what is logged when the UI is not rendering the tasks.

Comment: @GregFenton I rendered the app without adding a new task. When it renders, it doesn't display the logs. It happens just when I go to the Task tab. When I go to the Task tab for the first time, i get this:  LOG  num tasks: 0
 LOG  num filtered: 0
 LOG  num tasks: 19
 LOG  num filtered: 19. When I add a task, it logs: LOG  num tasks: 20
 LOG  num filtered: 20
 LOG  task item is: undefined. When I close, reopen and go to the Task tab, it logs: LOG  num tasks: 0
 LOG  num filtered: 0
 LOG  num tasks: 20
 LOG  num filtered: 20.

Comment: You will get the `0` because loading the data is asynchronous. On first render of your component, it initiates the call to fetch the data. When the data arrives, state is updated with the data, and that causes a subsequent render where you will see the number of items `19` or `20`.  So do you not see the `19` or `20` items?  Ugh...my previous suggested console.log() should have been: `console.log("task item is:", task);`  My bad.  You are passing `item` in the parent as `task` to the child....so you want to log `task` in the child (TaskContainer)

Comment: @GregFenton oh. Got it now. I update the console.log, and got this when I went to the Task tab: LOG  num tasks: 0
 LOG  num filtered: 0
 LOG  num tasks: 24
 LOG  num filtered: 24. Then this when I created the task: LOG  num tasks: 25
 LOG  num filtered: 25
 LOG  task item is: {"date": "", "taskDescription": "", "taskTitle": "C", "time": ""}, And back to this when reload the app: LOG  num tasks: 0
 LOG  num filtered: 0
 LOG  num tasks: 25
 LOG  num filtered: 25.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the getTasks call. ```export async function getTasks() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('select * from tasks', [], (_, { rows }) => {
        resolve(rows._array);
      });
    });
  });
};``` . I use the same pattern to get the notes: ```export async function getNotes() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('select * from notes', [], (_, { rows }) => {
        resolve(rows._array);
      });
    });
  });
};```, and had no problem at all.

Comment: You aren't showing the code that calls getTasks() or how the return value gets passed to your tasks variable in the task container.